# When I enabling Proguard the apk I get is missing the root kotlin folder and some properties files

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

When I enabling Proguard the apk I get is missing the root kotlin folder and some properties files.The picture I put below is the file I lost.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MICT5.png)

When the kotlin folder is missing, my app will crash as soon as it is started.

```
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.AssertionError: Built-in class kotlin.Any is not found
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns$3.invoke(KotlinBuiltIns.java:113)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns$3.invoke(KotlinBuiltIns.java:108)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getBuiltInClassByName(KotlinBuiltIns.java:362)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getAny(KotlinBuiltIns.java:367)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getAnyType(KotlinBuiltIns.java:642)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getNullableAnyType(KotlinBuiltIns.java:647)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.getDefaultBound(KotlinBuiltIns.java:652)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.TypeParameterDescriptorImpl.createWithDefaultBound(TypeParameterDescriptorImpl.java:56)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$MockClassDescriptor.<init>(NotFoundClasses.kt:55)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:44)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1.invoke(NotFoundClasses.kt:22)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:512)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:587)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses.getClass(NotFoundClasses.kt:92)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer$typeConstructor$1.invoke(TypeDeserializer.kt:109)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.typeConstructor(TypeDeserializer.kt:113)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.simpleType(TypeDeserializer.kt:75)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer.type(TypeDeserializer.kt:63)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer.valueParameters(MemberDeserializer.kt:417)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer.loadConstructor(MemberDeserializer.kt:342)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.computePrimaryConstructor(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:122)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.access$computePrimaryConstructor(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$primaryConstructor$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:65)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$primaryConstructor$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.getUnsubstitutedPrimaryConstructor(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:126)
11-17 20:23:17.168 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.computeConstructors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:129)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.access$computeConstructors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$constructors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:66)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$constructors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:34)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:355)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:474)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor.getConstructors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:137)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructorDescriptors(KClassImpl.kt:200)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:91)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:44)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:92)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getConstructors(Unknown Source:7)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructors(KClassImpl.kt:235)
11-17 20:23:17.169 22976 23157 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:144)
```

Is there any way to not lose these files when enabling Proguard